# Script produces errors I can't find

Tags: javascript, document.write

The ultimate aim is to return a page displaying the following sentence

> Once upon a time there was a GENDER named NAME 
>  who had a PET named PET NAME.

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">

var heroGender, heroName, petType, petName;

heroGender = window.prompt('Is the hero female or male? Enter F or M', 'F');

heroName = window.prompt('What is the hero\'s name?','');

petType = window.prompt('What type of pet does the hero have?','');

petName = window.prompt('What is name of the pet?','');

  document.write('Once upon a time there was a ');

if (heroGender == ('F'))
{
    document.write('girl');
}
else 
{
    document.write('boy');
}

document.write('Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + ' named ' + heroName '.''<BR>' +
                                    heroName + ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Could you explain what went wrong?  We see code, but unless we copy and run it, we don't know what went wrong.

Comment: One obvious problem is that you print out "Once upon a time there was a " **twice**.

Comment: You code `'.''<BR>'` which is a little incorrect syntax.

Comment: @John, creating a fiddle took me less time that it too you to write that comment. Be nice.

Comment: The `language` attribute of the `script` element has been deprecated long ago. Use `type="text/javascript"` instead (or nothing when using HTML 5/Living Standard). Moreover, you can't change things dynamically using `document.write`, so it's good to know you shouldn't use it in 'normal' scripts.

Comment: It is not "wrong" but you can write heroName = window.prompt('What is the hero\'s name?','');  as heroName = window.prompt("What is the hero's name?",""); to avoid the excaped single quote.

Comment: @pimvdb: I was being nice.  Teaching him to use this site well is much more valuable than whatever sort of niceness you were referring to.

Comment: @John Fisher: I'm not sure if you are talking to me or to mplugjan. I did not intend to be rude.

Comment: @pimvdb: Sorry, that was for mplungjan.  Not sure what happened there.

Answer (score 7):

**While your waiting for the books!**

Learn from [Mozilla Developer Centre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn) !

**An Example:**

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/ELvQV/3/)

**Fixed version**

```
document.write(
    'Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + 
    ' named ' + heroName  + '.' + '<BR>' + heroName + 
    ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```

**Broken version**

You were missing to `+` symbols.

```
document.write(
    'Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + 
    ' named ' + heroName /* + */ '.' /* + */ '<BR>' + heroName + 
    ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```

Try using

- Firefox and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and its console tab (Hit F12)
- IE9 and the build in console (Hit F12. Make sure the console is open then refresh).
- Chrome and the build in console (Hit Ctrl+Shift+J)

To watch for any error messages.

If that's too much effort then try

```
window.onerror = function(e) {
  alert(e.message);
}
```

Here's an "improved" more standards compliant version. [Example Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/ELvQV/6/)

**HTML:**

```
<label> Your Hero's gender </label><input id="heroGender"/><br/>
<label> Your Hero's name </label><input id="heroName"/><br/>
<label> Your Hero's pet type </label><input id="petType"/><br/>
<label> Your Hero's pet name </label><input id="petName"/><br/>
<button> Make me a hero! </button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// make your hero when you press the button
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // get all the values from the text boxes
    var gender = document.getElementById("heroGender").value,
        name = document.getElementById("heroName").value,
        petType = document.getElementById("petType").value,
        petName = document.getElementById("petName").value;

    // set the text on your output.
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = 
        "Once upon a time there was a " + gender +
        " named " + name + ". " + name + " had a pet " + 
        petType + " called " + petName;


}, false);
```

The above code will break for IE8 or less :(. Making JavaScript work cross browser is a right pain.

So I you could read the documentation for browsers at

- [Firefox's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs)
- Microsoft [JavaScript docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0(v=vs.85).aspx) and [HTML docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050(v=vs.85).aspx)

But those are not easy to read or navigate. A great visual guide for cross browser scripting is the [visibone BrowserBook](http://www.visibone.com/products/browserbook.html).

It will show cross browser support (red is firefox, blue is IE) :

[image]

Give it a few months and you'll know how to use all that comfortably.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate that.  There was an error in the lines above that though.  The debugger ended at Line 9,

Comment: +1 for giving tools and methods not just pure answers to "homework" question.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer.  I will certainly start using Firebug.  I am awaiting my JS books arriving from Amazon.

Comment: @ZenProcrastination I hope you bought "The definitive Guide, 6th edition". That's a great book. Personally I like the chrome debugging tools the best myself. `console.log` and `console.dir` are my friend :)

Comment: No I purchased Javascript Bible and Definitive Javascript by O'Reilly.  I also have Chrome so I will try a range of tools.  This was my first program and to be honest...I am quite loving it despite making mistakes.

Comment: @ZenProcrastination I meant the definitive JavaScript by OReilly ;) That's a great book. See my learn from mozilla and visibone link.

Comment: @ZenProcrastination if I've answered your question you should click the green tick on next to my question to mark it as answered.

Comment: I would think addEventListener which will break in IE9 is not helping a beginner. Just use onclick="makeMeAHero()" or document.getElementById('buttonId').click=function() {...}

Comment: @mplungjan `addEventListener` is supported in IE9. `onclick` and `click` are bad practice. Yes it's a pain to support IE8, but I rather not start off with teaching bad practices.

Comment: Ok it was you who said your code would break in IE9. I do not see click or onclick as bad practises compared to forcing the use of something not supported by all browsers just for the sake of purism

Comment: @mplungjan Purism is important. We need to adhere to web standards or we'll never shackle IE6. Normally I would just feature detect for `attachEvent` but that's obscuring the point. IE8 is a legacy browser anyway so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Raynos meanwhile in the real world, we have to fully support IE6 which is still in use by major corporations who cannot be persuaded to upgrade. I respect your point of view but do not share it. What works for all browsers is what I need to use rather than what looks good at Stackoverflow. I can tell your that IE8 is NOT a legacy browser where Windows 7 is not installed. Stats from my site this week: 95285115 hits - 0.9% IE9, 28% IE8, 18% IE7, 31% IE6

Comment: @mplungjan yes browser support is important, I didn't want to complicate the example with browser support. It is however better to code to the web standards then do feature detection for older browsers.

Comment: @Raynos or be pragmatic and use .onclick=function... which will work in ALL browsers :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you had some typos in your final document.write.You're missing a '+' after heroName... and you've got some duplicative document.writes.

Here's what I believe should be your final code:

```
var heroGender, heroName, petType, petName;
heroGender = window.prompt('Is the hero female or male? Enter F or M', 'F');
heroName = window.prompt('What is the hero\'s name?','');
petType = window.prompt('What type of pet does the hero have?','');
petName = window.prompt('What is name of the pet?','');

if (heroGender == ('F')) { heroGender ='girl'; } else { heroGender = 'boy'; }
document.write('Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + ' named ' + heroName + '. ' + heroName + ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Too many quotes and a missing plus

```
Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
Line: 41, Column: 83
Source Code:
document.write('Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + ' named ' + heroName '.''<BR>' +
```

should be

```
document.write(' named ' + heroName + '.<BR>' + 
heroName + ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zHGsD/

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in this line:

```
document.write('Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + ' named ' + heroName '.''<BR>' + heroName + ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```

specifically, here:

```
heroName '.''<BR>' + heroName
```

If you change it to this, your should work as expected:

```
document.write(' named ' + heroName + ' who had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```

Notice that I also removed the redundancy from the first part of the phrase, since you already included it before your "if 'F', then 'girl'" statement.

Comment: Thank you for the redundancy comment.  I was puzzled my self by that but the way the question was structured made it look like the sentence was required both before and after.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write('Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + ' named ' + heroName **+** '.' **+** '<BR>' +
                                    heroName + ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```

I got it to run by adding the two `+` that I've wrapped in `**`

Comment: Awesome.  Thankyou  :-)  shame it is too late to get the marks but experience is the name we give to our mistakes.

Comment: @ZenProcrastination: Glad to answer. I work on answers more to solve the problem and enhance my personal knowledge. I then share the answers to help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your last line. Corrected as follow

```
document.write('Once upon a time there was a ' + heroGender + ' named ' + heroName + '.' + '<BR>' + heroName + ' had a ' + petType + ' called ' + petName + '.');
```